# Android multiline SQLite command

Tags: android, database, sqlite

If you have a string representation of a multiline SQLite command, is there any way to execute without looping through each command. IE `sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(statement)`

Comment: Have you tried executing the commands separated by semicolons (;)?

Comment: @coproc Please see my answer below about using semi-colons.

Answer (score 2):

You must call each command separately.
I assume you are just double-checking, but the `execSQL()` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29) is quite clear:

> **Parameters**
>   *sql*   the SQL statement to be executed. Multiple statements separated by semicolons are not supported.

---

The same is true for the matching [`rawQuery()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d%29) method:

> **Parameters**
>   *sql*   the SQL query. The SQL string must not be ; terminated